# How to take a photo using ICCameraDevice?

Tags: macos, cocoa, photo, image-capture

I am trying to get a Mac app working with a Canon Mark II 5D.

Basically I want to be able to click a button and snap a photo, retrieve the photo, and display it.  There is a lot more I am doing, but this is the part I am having trouble with.

Anyway, I am using the `ICDeviceBrowser` to find devices, and I am able to find it.  I set it as my decive using the following delgate method.

```
- (void)deviceBrowser:(ICDeviceBrowser*)browser didAddDevice:(ICDevice*)addedDevice moreComing:(BOOL)moreComing {

    ICCameraDevice *thisCamera = (ICCameraDevice*)addedDevice;
    thisCamera.delegate = self;

    self.camera = thisCamera;

    [self.camera requestOpenSession];

}
```

Then to fire off the camera I would think I would do this...but nothing is happening.

```
[self.camera requestTakePicture];
```

Has anyone ever played with this, or might know what's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Hope this isn't too late and is useful to you. The reason why the button method works is because the device is ready by the time you go to press it. If you want to automate the capture, you need to listen out for the `deviceDidBecomeReady` and `didOpenSessionWithError` delegates.

`device:(ICDevice *)device didOpenSessionWithError:(NSError *)error` will enable you to enable tethering and `deviceDidBecomeReady` will enable you to perform camera functions. It sucks that Apple hasn't documented this at all!

```
- (void) deviceDidBecomeReady:(ICDevice *)device {
     [_camera requestTakePicture];
}

- (void) device:(ICDevice *)device didOpenSessionWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [_camera requestEnableTethering];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check what ICCameraDevice think about taking pictures via

```
self.camera.canTakePictures
```

and

```
BOOL canYou = [self.capabilities containsObject:ICCameraDeviceCanTakePicture]
```

also, see about camera connection mode [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1085). and [here](https://github.com/jpld/CameraObscura/blob/master/CameraObscuraPlugIn.m) implementation of the downloading process from camera.

Comment: IT definitely has that.  Part of the capabilities is: ICCameraDeviceCanTakePicture

Comment: I don't what app should do, but did you try to use [QTKit Capture](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/UsingQTKit/UsingQTKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008156-CH108-SW9)? some functions explained [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationTutorial/BuildingaSimpleQTKitCaptureApplication/BuildingaSimpleQTKitCaptureApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008155-CH8-SW1) and [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MYRecorder/Introduction/Intro.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually just found out this worked, however, the requestTakePicture needs to be fired with a button.  I was just trying to fire it after it had opened the session.