# requestTakePicture() doesn't do anything

Tags: swift, macos, image-capture, ptp

I'm trying to make a DSLR Photo Booth app for Mac that controls a Nikon Z6 r Z7 connected via USB. I'm trying to do this in Swift, using ImageCaptureCore.

I'm able to init the ICDeviceBrowser and open a session to the camera. The deviceDidBecomeReady However, calling

```
device.requestTakePicture()
```

doesn't do *anything*.

The device does have the ICCameraDeviceCanTakePicture capability:

```
{
    UUIDString = "00000030-3030-3030-3033-303432303637";
    autolaunchApplicationPath = "";
    capabilities =     (
        ICCameraDeviceCanSyncClock,
        ICCameraDeviceCanTakePicture,
        ICCameraDeviceCanDeleteOneFile,
        ICCameraDeviceCanAcceptPTPCommands
    );
    class = ICCameraDevice;
    connectionID = 0xffff0002;
    delegate = "<0x600002fbbd50>";
    deviceID = 0xffff0002;
    deviceRef = 0xffff0002;
    iconPath = "(null)";
    locationDescription = ICDeviceLocationDescriptionUSB;
    moduleExecutableArchitecture = 0;
    modulePath = "/System/Library/Image Capture/Devices/PTPCamera.app";
    moduleVersion = "1.0";
    name = "Z 7";
    persistentIDString = "00000030-3030-3030-3033-303432303637";
    shared = NO;
    softwareInstallPercentDone = "0.000000";
    transportType = ICTransportTypeUSB;
    type = 0x00000101;
}  timeOffset                    : 0.000000
  hasConfigurableWiFiInterface  : N/A
  isAccessRestrictedAppleDevice : NO
```

I am getting device.tetheredCaptureEnabled() == false, but the capability exists.

> @property tetheredCaptureEnabled
> @abstract This property is always set to YES when the device has the capability 'ICCameraDeviceCanTakePicture'

So I'd expect this to be true, since the capability exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to take a photo using ICCameraDevice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8957451/how-to-take-a-photo-using-iccameradevice)